# Calculate difference in means

Tags: stata

The variable `bwght` gives the birthweight of the baby (in ounces).

What is  the difference in average birthweight between smoking and non-smoking mothers?

How do I do subtraction of means in Stata?

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please also consider up-voting it using the upper arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this using the `auto` toy dataset as an example:

```
sysuse auto, clear

summarize price if foreign
local mean1 = r(mean)

summarize price if !foreign
local mean2 = r(mean)
```

If you just want to see the result you can use the `display` command:

```
display `mean1' - `mean2'
312.25874
```

If you want to save the result in a variable you can use the `generate` command:

```
generate mean_price = `mean1' - `mean2'

list mean_price in 1, abbreviate(10)

     +------------+
     | mean_price |
     |------------|
  1. |   312.2587 |
     +------------+
```

You can also use the `mean` command, instead of `summarize`:

```
mean price, over(foreign)
matrix A = r(table)

display A[1,2] - A[1,1]
312.25874

generate mean_price = A[1,2] - A[1,1]

list mean_price in 1, abbreviate(10)

     +------------+
     | mean_price |
     |------------|
  1. |   312.2587 |
     +------------+
```

---

**EDIT:**

A comment by Nick Cox

You can also use the `regress` command:

```
regress price foreign 


      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        74
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 72)        =      0.17
       Model |  1507382.66         1  1507382.66   Prob > F        =    0.6802
    Residual |   633558013        72  8799416.85   R-squared       =    0.0024
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =   -0.0115
       Total |   635065396        73  8699525.97   Root MSE        =    2966.4

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     foreign |   312.2587   754.4488     0.41   0.680    -1191.708    1816.225
       _cons |   6072.423    411.363    14.76   0.000     5252.386     6892.46
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The difference in means is the coefficient of the variable `foreign`, which you can access afterwards with `_b[foreign]`. That is going to be true for any binary predictor whose codes differ by one (for example, `0` and `1`, `1` and `2`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `ttest` command:

```
webuse fuel3            (setup)
ttest mpg, by(treated)  (two-sample t test using groups)
```

For you, that is:

```
ttest bwght, by(smoking)
```